# Getting error ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: oracle

I am new to LOB data type, i am getting error will execute this procedure script as below....

```
CREATE TABLE SA_ZIP_TEST (
   SEQ          NUMBER,
   STRING_BLOB  BLOB,
   STRING_CLOB  CLOB,
   DT           DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ZIP(src IN clob, dst IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB )
IS
BEGIN
   IF src is not null THEN
      DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(dst, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
      XML_ZIP_PKG_2.ZIP_CLOB(src, dst);
      DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(dst);
   END IF;
END ZIP;
```

Will execute the below script getting an error message ORA-22275

```
DECLARE
   V_Query_Str VARCHAR2 (4000);
   V_RESULT CLOB; 
   V_RESULT2 bLOB;
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result, TRUE, dbms_lob.session);
   FOR I IN 1..100
   LOOP
      V_Query_Str:=
         'INSERT INTO SA_ZIP_TEST
            (seq
            ,DT
            ,STRING_BLOB
            )
         VALUES
            (:Cmd_Seq
            ,:Cmd_DT 
            ,:Result)
      ';
      xml_zip_pkg_2.ZIP(V_Result,V_RESULT2);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_Query_Str USING I, SYSDATE,V_RESULT2 ;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

`V_RESULT2` becomes invalid locator after invocation of `xml_zip_pkg_2.ZIP(V_Result,V_RESULT2);` because of `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(dst);` inside `ZIP`

Comment: xml_zip_pkg_2 is packaged in that I have ZIP procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You are freeing the BLOB before the caller has a chance to do anything with it. But you don't need to create it either really, since it's declared by the caller - you would only need to create it if the parameter was `OUT`, rather than `IN OUT`. So your procedure only needs to do:

```
   IF src is not null THEN
      DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(dst, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
      XML_ZIP_PKG_2.ZIP_CLOB(src, dst);
   END IF;
```

The caller can (and should) still free the BLOB after using it:

```
      ZIP(V_Result,V_RESULT2);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_Query_Str USING I, SYSDATE,V_RESULT2 ;
      DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(V_RESULT2);
```

Or after the loop. It might be more efficient to create the temporary BLOB once in the caller, before the loop, and free it at the end; then your procedure can do:

```
   IF src is not null THEN
      XML_ZIP_PKG_2.ZIP_CLOB(src, dst);
   END IF;
```

And the caller can do:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result, TRUE, dbms_lob.session);
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result2, TRUE, dbms_lob.call);
   FOR I IN 1..100
   LOOP
      ..
      ZIP(V_Result,V_RESULT2);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_Query_Str USING I, SYSDATE,V_RESULT2 ;
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(V_RESULT2);
END;
```

Although you can define `V_Query_Str` once, and this doesn't need to use dynamic SQL at all:

```
DECLARE
   V_RESULT CLOB; 
   V_RESULT2 bLOB;
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result, TRUE, dbms_lob.session);
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result2, TRUE, dbms_lob.call);
   FOR I IN 1..100 LOOP
      ZIP(V_Result,V_RESULT2);
      INSERT INTO SA_ZIP_TEST
         (seq
          ,DT
           ,STRING_BLOB
           )
         VALUES
           (i
           ,sysdate 
           ,V_RESULT2);
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(V_RESULT2);
END;
/
```

[Here's an SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37128/1), using `converttoblob` as we don't have your package.

Comment: Thanks Alex Sorry xml_zip_pkg_2 is PACKAGE in that I have ZIP procedure. i just create individual procedure ZIP.But Alex i have change as below but still getting the error message            DECLARE V_Query_Str VARCHAR2 (4000);
V_RESULT CLOB;  V_RESULT2 bLOB;
BEGIN DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result, TRUE, dbms_lob.session);
FOR I IN 1..100  LOOP V_Query_Str:='INSERT INTO SA_ZIP_TEST
(seq,DT,STRING_BLOB) VALUES (:Cmd_Seq,:Cmd_DT,:Result)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_Query_Str USING I, SYSDATE,V_Result;
IF V_RESULT is not null THEN
      ZIP(V_RESULT, V_RESULT2);
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;

Comment: Still getting error as you mention about points Error report -
ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified
ORA-06512: at line 9
22275. 00000 -  "invalid LOB locator specified"

Comment: @user3098484 - you're now populating `v_result2` after the `execute immediate`, which doesn't make sense; and you're using `v_result` in the insert instead of `v_result2`, which gives an ORA-00932 not ORA-22275. I'm not sure what you're running now to get that. You can see form the Fiddle that this works, so you'll need to see what you're doing differently.

Comment: Alex is doing as you told script below create PROCEDURE ZIP(src IN clob, dst OUT BLOB )   IS BEGIN  IF src is not null THEN 
DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(dst, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
XML_ZIP_PKG_2.ZIP_CLOB(src, dst);
DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(dst); END IF; END ZIP;

Comment: Execution as DECLARE    V_RESULT CLOB;     V_RESULT2 bLOB;
BEGIN
DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result, TRUE, dbms_lob.session);
DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_Result2, TRUE, dbms_lob.call);
FOR I IN 1..10 LOOP   ZIP(V_Result,V_RESULT2);
INSERT INTO SA_ZIP_TEST (seq ,DT ,STRING_BLOB)
VALUES (i,sysdate ,V_RESULT2);
END LOOP;  DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(V_RESULT2); END;

Comment: @user3098484 - that isn't what I said; the `zip` procedure should not be doing `createtemporary` *or* `freetemporary`, as the caller is doing both. It only needs to call `zip_clob`. (And `src` can never be null in this scenario, so that check might be pointless too, so you might as well just call `zip_clob` directly?).